# google app scripts service called too many times

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 5 active scripts that are each run every minute.

Now Google refuses to run the scripts and returns the following message (German):
Folgender Dienst an einem Tag zu häufig aufgerufen: gmail read (line 114)

Here is the corresponding code:

- line 114   `var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('cas');`
- line 115   `var threads = label.getThreads();`

I suppose that there is a limit on how often I am allowed to fetch mails.
Does anybody know what this limit is, or any solution that still allows me to check
mails ever minute?

Answer (score 0):

see https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard for quotas, 10000 calls per day for gmail